# How to remove items from a slice safely since the # of items in the slice is changing

Tags: go

**Once I iterate over the users slice, I need to then remove some of the users from the slice based on some condition.  I will be looping over this users slice many times, slowly removing some elements.**

I know from other languages it isn't safe to remove items from a collection while you are looping.  So what I am doing is storing the elements I want removed in a map `toMutate`.  Once my original loop is finished, I then go ahead and try to remove the elements from the slice.

```
toMutate := make(map[int]User, 100)
for idx, u := range c.users {
  if someCondition {
    toMutate[idx] = u
  }
}
```

I then call this function to remove the items from the user's slice.

```
for idx, u := range toMutate {
  c.users = append(c.users[:idx], c.users[idx+1:]...)
}
```

Now I get an error:

> panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

I think I know why I am getting the error. Each iteration I am removing an element from the slice.
So now my idx value is off since the # of items has changed.

How do you deal with situations like this?

Comment: I don't known what is your actual intention is, but I think you are doing it in the wrong way. Why don't you use map only. Can you elaborate the question with some context.

Comment: Given that use case, it might be better to just use a map for your data structure rather than a slice.  Would that work for your purposes?  Maps are not ordered, though you can impose a sort order on demand.

Comment: @jrefior order is import when I iterate, I need to sort by the time.Time property of user.

Comment: @Blankman One easy approach is to sort the indices marked for removal in reverse order and then delete the elements starting from the largest index first.

Comment: What about using a struct that has a boolean field for a soft delete?  Then you can skip deleted values when you iterate over the slice of those structs.

Comment: @nilsocket I updated my question (bold) with more context.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is more efficient than the holding it in map, and re-slicing, for every value to remove.

```
func updateUser(users []User) []User {

    temp := make([]User, 0, len(users))

    for _, u := range users {
        if !condition(u) {
            temp = append(temp, u)
        }
    }
    return temp
}
```

But something which would be more better is to use some other data structure, like linked list or something which is optimized for deletes.

Arrays(slices) aren't efficient for removing elements in between.

Comment: "As everybody know" is not very helpful on a Q&A site - not everyone knows things, and many users reading answers on SO are newer developers who may not know this and shouldn't be made to feel bad about that.

Comment: Moreover, in many cases using slices and value copying is the most performant way to do things, due to caching and hash binning issues. "Maps" (hash maps) are not some magical things that always make things better. :-)

Comment: @oakad It's better to copy, but not when it's more frequently updated, In OP case for every element which is being removed, re-slicing and then copying rest of the elements several times is going to be heavier than one thinks. Consider for every minute you get 100 users and 70 users are deleting their account. This solution will never workout, It's better to use some other data structure.

Comment: @Adrian but OP has 92k reputation, anyhow I'm removed it.

Comment: @nilsocket As I'm usually too lazy to write proper answers, I simply extended my comment to answer the OP's immediate question. Clearly, in production, one would sort indices in ascending order and compact the surviving values toward the beginning of the slice using a bit of index trickery, truncating the slice once post iteration. And only a substantial benchmarking will be able to discern whether map based approach can beat that (I'd say - highly unlikely). :-)

Answer (score 1):

The genera idea goes as following:

```
toMutate := []int {}
for idx := range c.users {
    if someCondition {
        toMutate = append(toMutate, idx)
    }
}
//...
sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(toMutate)))
//...
for _, u := range toMutate {
   c.users = append(c.users[:u], c.users[u+1:]...)
}
```